# JMeter Property to Specify Path of current file?

Tags: jmeter

Is there a property or function in JMeter that can specify the path to the folder from which the `Test Plan` has been opened?

Answer (score 3):

In majority of cases, i.e. in [Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) you can use `~/` as location, relative to current .jmx file which is being executed.

However if you need the full path for any reason you can use [__Beanshell()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) function to get it like:

```
${__BeanShell(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir())}
```

References:

- [FileServer class JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/services/FileServer.html)
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

Comment: @JusMe Please double check your statements prior to posting them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this from a beanshell script. Here is what I am doing in my script

[image]